# Get backlinks by wordpress or any other plugin development?

Tags: facebook, wordpress, drupal, plugins, joomla

I want to ask that if I develop a plugin in wordpress or joomla or drupal or any other website and put the Visit website and support links inside the plugin page, then will these be considered as backlinks?? Means if any website having page rank of 6 installs my plugin then will I be getting a backlink from page rank 6 website?

See my website is [PluginsTalk.com](http://PluginsTalk.com) where I posts articles related to plugins. I've also developed some plugins for my personal website development as I didn't find them on wordpress. So if I submit my plugins to wordpress then will I get backlinks from every website that installs it.?

**My other most important question is that** : the plugin can be used only from admin section (it doesn't add/affect the main website, only dashboard), **then links to plugin settings page will be considered as backlink?** Because it is shown only at the administration area not the actual website.

*I want to start plugins development of plugins for my website [PluginsTalk.com](http://PluginsTalk.com) only if they provide me backlink. Otherwise I'll keep them to myself only.*

Please reply with a yes or no included in answer so that I can understand clearly.

Thanks. Enjoy your day. Develop :)

---

Addition: I want to ask same thing about developing **facebook apps**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. This isn't going to get you any rank.

Unless the search engines can crawl the admin section of the CMS's you name this scheme isn't going to work. I am fairly confident that you have to login to get to the admin sections though. That means that the search engines will never know about your links and if the engines don't know about them, no rank. The engine has to see the link for it to matter, and you state that nothing on the front end changes.

Answer (score 1):

In wordpress the admin is area that is the Dashboard is mostly restricted for the crawl robots.

So there wont be any juice for your links if they are in the dashboard.

ps:-

For more info check robots.txt

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow: /wp-admin/
Disallow: /wp-includes/
Disallow: /wp-content/
```

Comment: In WordPress, you can't get to the dashboard without logging in. Crawlers do not log in.

Comment: Thanks Ketan for help. I got my answer.